# Is there a way to isolate parts of a string?

Tags: python

I was trying to split some parts of a string, to completely isolate only parts of a string. Below, for example, I was trying to isolate the open share price of Kimberly-Clark Corp.

I've tried to use `.split()`, however that means I can only isolate the open price on one side. For example, if it looks like this,

```
'1. open': '131.8600', '2. high': '132.0500', '3. low': '131.7900', '4. close': '132.0400', '5. volume': '76708'}, '2019-11-01 15:55:00':
```

I can only use .split() to get

```
131.8600','2. high': '132.0500', '3. low': '131.7900', '4. close': '132.0400', '5. volume': '76708'}, '2019-11-01 15:55:00':
```

## for example

```py
r = requests.get(https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=kmb&interval=5min&apikey=exampleapikey)

cont = json.loads(r.content.decode())

cont= str(cont)

ali = cont.split("{")


for x in range(9):
  if x!= 1 and x!=0: 
    print(ali[x]+"\n")

  else:
    x+=1
```

## returns

```
'2019-11-01 16:00:00':

'1. open': '131.8600', '2. high': '132.0500', '3. low': '131.7900', '4. close': '132.0400', '5. volume': '76708'}, '2019-11-01 15:55:00':

'1. open': '131.6600', '2. high': '131.8700', '3. low': '131.6500', '4. close': '131.8600', '5. volume': '46212'}, '2019-11-01 15:50:00':

'1. open': '131.8800', '2. high': '131.8800', '3. low': '131.6500', '4. close': '131.6500', '5. volume': '17977'}, '2019-11-01 15:45:00':

'1. open': '131.8800', '2. high': '131.9100', '3. low': '131.8500', '4. close': '131.8800', '5. volume': '9575'}, '2019-11-01 15:40:00':

'1. open': '131.7300', '2. high': '131.9050', '3. low': '131.7300', '4. close': '131.8800', '5. volume': '12393'}, '2019-11-01 15:35:00':
```

I can't seem to figure this out. apologies in advance for the confusing language

Comment: which part of the string would you like to isolate? is it the number after `open`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using string manipulation for this at all; you should be traversing the dict you got from `json.loads`.

Comment: Please format the code and data  - select it and type `ctrl-k` . [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: json.loads(request.text) will make a dictionary out of this, use it

Comment: @wwii i requested the edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't use string-manipulation. The GET-request gives you everything you could possibly want in a cute JSON format. Take advantage of that:

```
def main():

    import requests
    import json

    url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=kmb&interval=5min&apikey=exampleapikey"

    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    open_share_price = data["Time Series (5min)"]["2019-11-01 16:00:00"]["1. open"]
    print(open_share_price)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
131.8600
```

Comment: I am confused.
The question contained already a `json.loads()` and the shown quotes were single quotes

Comment: My guess is that the OP simply copied parts of code they've seen online to try and make it work, without really understanding what it's for or what features are available to them. What difference do the single quotes make?

Comment: try `json.loads("{'a': 'b'}")` instead of `json.loads('{"a": "b"}') ` and you'll see, that the json parser will fail

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. In any case the `response.text` I get back seems to be using double-quotes anyway - here's what that looks like: `'{\n    "Meta Data": {\n        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high,`...

Comment: snif. It means I was working under wrong assumptions. Probably better I delete my answer then I guess?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it like so?

```py
r = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=kmb&interval=5min&apikey=exampleapikey")

cont = json.loads(r.content.decode())

cont= str(cont)

ali = cont.split("{")


for x in range(9):
  if x!= 1 and x!=0: 
    price=ali[x].split(':')[1].split(',')[0]
    print(price+"\n")

  else:
    x+=1
```